# c# boolean operators - normal vs. short-circuit

Tags: c#

question regarding BOOLEAN operator '|' and '||'. The only difference I can find between these two operators is; when using '||' [the right side of the expression will not be evaluated if the left side is true.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Outside of person preference why would one use '|' over '||' for boolean testing?

```
if(true | false)
{
do something
}

vs 
if (true || false)
{
do something
}
```

Comment: To make sure that the right side of the expression is also evaluated even though the left side is true, or am I now just stating the obvious? Couldn't it be possible that you want to execute 2 operations yet if only one of them results in true, something else needs to happen? Seems like a possible case to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's primarily an issue if the operation has side effects:

Consider the following:

```
using(IEnumerator iterator1 = args.GetEnumerator())
using (IEnumerator iterator2 = args.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator1.MoveNext() | iterator2.MoveNext())
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Because the `MoveNext` operations cause side effects it may be important for *both* sides of the `|` to be executed regardless of whether the first is true.

Comment: In case of `&` there is another difference: booleans don't have to be 0 or 1 on the CLR so `(bool)1 & (bool)2` is `false`! (Not valid C# but can be constructed using IL).

Comment: @usr - not that I ever encountered such situation, but indeed I've also heard it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

> why would one use '|' over '||' for boolean testing?

If (for some reason) the right side has side-effects that you need to occur.

This is generally not good practice, however.

Answer (score 3):

> Outside of person preference why would one use '|' over '||' for boolean testing?

Precisely because you *might* want both sides to be evaluated. There may be side-effects which you need to occur either way.

It's rare, but it's feasible.

Comment: And also the cause of "fun" bugs. :)