# LINQ extension method throwing error when I enter a email and password combination (System.InvalidOperarationException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

LINQ extension method throwing error when I enter a email and password combination that does not exist on my database.

Error: System.InvalidOperationException {"Sequence contains no elements"}

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin userlogin)
    {          

        ViewBag.LoginError = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //no validation errors
           //userContext.Users gives a list with all users on databse
           //here is my linq query to select the user with valid email and password combination

            User loggedInUser = (from user in userContext.Users
                                 where user.EmailId == userlogin.UserEmail & user.Password == userlogin.UserPassword
                                 select user).First();//Error Source

            if (loggedInUser != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ValidUser = loggedInUser;
                return RedirectToAction("UserHomePage", "UserHome");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.LoginError = "Invalid User name and Password Combination";
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) and not `First` - this will return `null` if no elements are found. You should also generally use the [short circuit `&&` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325311/c-sharp-boolean-operators-normal-vs-short-circuit) (not `&`) unless you intentionally want both expressions to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no user with the given username password combination, then the query:

```
from user in userContext.Users
where user.EmailId == userlogin.UserEmail & user.Password == userlogin.UserPassword
select user
```

will result in no objects, and calling `First()` on it will throw that exception.

Have you considered using [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead: if there are no objects then it will return null (assuming `user` is a reference type).